# System.getProperty("User.dir") возвращает null

Tags: java, файлы

Здравствуйте!
Есть некий класс, ответственный за директорию игры у пользователя.
В нем есть приватное поле типа File

```
private static File gameDir = new File(System.getProperty("User.dir") + "/BallsGame");
```

Так вот, при попытке получить его путь или начать работать с ним, путь оказывается таким - "Null\BallsGame".
В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для доступа к системным свойствам нужно использовать ключи в нижнем регистре. Посмотрите спецификацию [здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html). В вашем случае должно быть:

```
private static File gameDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/BallsGame");
```

Answer (score 2):

Имя чувтвительно к регистру, надо указывать `user.dir`, в не `User.dir`.

P.S. Судя по контексту, с большой вероятностью вам нужно свойство `user.home`.